# how to pass Bound value (asp.net control ) to a jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, tooltip

Let me explain what I am trying to do.

I have a asp.net gridview and one of the bound columns is a label field showing count, say 100, but in the code behind I have the spilt up of how I got that value. So on hover over the label I want to show something like labor = 30, material = 50, cost = 20

This is my aspx code

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Cost" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign=Center ItemStyle-VerticalAlign=Middle>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" Text='<%# Eval("TotalCost")%>' runat=server></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

- Question 1:
  can i override tooltip template just like WPF/silverlight to show this infromation
- Question 2
  if i need to use jquery to show a small window as tooltip on hover over, then how do i pass the details like labor = 30, material = 50, cost = 20 to the jquery
- question 3
  can i do this in javascript

`<asp:Label ID="Label2" Text=MYJavascriptFunction('<%# Eval("TotalCost")%>') runat=server  onmouseover ></asp:Label>`

i.e first bound value will go to my javascript function and it will process something and return a text that will be used in the asp:Label Text.

Please point me in right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the ToolTip property of the Label control, and bind it to display your data:

```
<asp:label ID="Label2" Text='<%# Eval("TotalCost")%>' ToolTip='<%# String.Format("Labor={0}, Material={1}, Cost={2}", eval("labor"), eval("material"), eval("cost")) %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

This is rendered as the "Title" property of the `<span>` tag that is output by the Label control.

Comment: this worked just fine. thank you. but i was trying to make the tool tip customizable. like may be image and that sort ...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create your own custom tooltip, here's a basic implementation:

You can create an attribute on your `<asp:Label>` called `data-costfactors` that can hold the information to display on hover (using jQuery) and add the `CssClass="total"` attribute to the label as well

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Cost" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" 
            CssClass="total" 
            Text='<%# Eval("TotalCost")%>' 
            data-costfactors='<%# Eval("CostFactors") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Where `CostFactors` in your datasource looks something like "labor = 30, material = 50, cost = 20"

Setup your tooltip html element like so:

```
<div id="tooltip"></div>
```

Style the tooltip div with some simple CSS:

```
#tooltip {display:none;position:absolute;border:solid 1px;background:#fff;}
```

Then with jQuery you can setup your tooltip with the `data-costfactors` attribute value like so:

```
$(function () {
    var $tooltip = $('#tooltip');

    $('.total').hover(function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $tooltip.html($this.data('costfactors')).show();
    }, function () {
        $tooltip.hide();
    }).mousemove(function (e) {
        $tooltip.css({
            top: (e.pageY + 15) + "px",
            left: (e.pageX + 15) + "px"
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I could not get this working. $this.data('costfactors') gives me undefined. But the idea looks right. Thanks

Comment: possibly not working due to an older version of jquery, you can try `$this.attr('data-costfactors')` instead